# Python - get all in order splits of a string

Tags: python, python-itertools

That is, for a sentence break it up into all possible combinations of in-order words, with no words omitted

For example, for input
"The cat sat on the mat"

output

```
[("The", "cat sat on the mat"),
("The cat", "sat on the mat"),  
("The cat", "sat", "on the mat")] #etc
```

but not

```
("The mat", "cat sat on the") # out of order
("The cat"), ("mat") # words missing
```

I looked at methods in itertools, but can't see that they do the job, as combinations will miss items out ("the cat", "mat") and permutations will change the order.

Am I missing something in these tools, or are they just not right ones?

(For the sake of clarity, this is not a question about how to split a string, but how to get combinations)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Just to clarify, we're starting with `"The cat sat on the mat".split(' ')`, which returns `['The', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'the', 'mat']`?

Comment: Yes, with a list, already split

Comment: OK, and would `("The cat", "sat", "on", "the mat")` also be an output that you expect?

Comment: Yes. Every conceivable way of breaking it down without changing order or missing a word out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying [Raymond Hettinger's partition recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576795/) for Python 3 as inspired by [this blog post](http://wordaligned.org/articles/partitioning-with-python) from WordAligned, and every partition case with your list, we can accomplish this with `chain` and `combinations` from itertools.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
def partition(iterable):
    n = len(input_list)
    b, mid, e = [0], list(range(1, n)), [n]
    getslice = input_list.__getitem__
    splits = (d for i in range(n) for d in combinations(mid, i))
    return [[input_list[sl] for sl in map(slice, chain(b, d), chain(d, e))]
            for d in splits]
```

**Demo**:

```
>>> print(partition(input_list))
[[['The', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'the', 'mat']], [['The'], ['cat', 'sat', 'on', 'the', 'mat']], [['The', 'cat'], ['sat', 'on', 'the', 'mat']], [['The', 'cat', 'sat'], ['on', 'the', 'mat']], [['The', 'cat', 'sat', 'on'], ['the', 'mat']], [['The', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'the'], ['mat']], [['The'], ['cat'], ['sat', 'on', 'the', 'mat']], [['The'], ['cat', 'sat'], ['on', 'the', 'mat']], [['The'], ['cat', 'sat', 'on'], ['the', 'mat']], [['The'], ['cat', 'sat', 'on', 'the'], ['mat']], [['The', 'cat'], ['sat'], ['on', 'the', 'mat']], [['The', 'cat'], ['sat', 'on'], ['the', 'mat']], [['The', 'cat'], ['sat', 'on', 'the'], ['mat']], [['The', 'cat', 'sat'], ['on'], ['the', 'mat']], [['The', 'cat', 'sat'], ['on', 'the'], ['mat']], [['The', 'cat', 'sat', 'on'], ['the'], ['mat']], [['The'], ['cat'], ['sat'], ['on', 'the', 'mat']], [['The'], ['cat'], ['sat', 'on'], ['the', 'mat']], [['The'], ['cat'], ['sat', 'on', 'the'], ['mat']], [['The'], ['cat', 'sat'], ['on'], ['the', 'mat']], [['The'], ['cat', 'sat'], ['on', 'the'], ['mat']], [['The'], ['cat', 'sat', 'on'], ['the'], ['mat']], [['The', 'cat'], ['sat'], ['on'], ['the', 'mat']], [['The', 'cat'], ['sat'], ['on', 'the'], ['mat']], [['The', 'cat'], ['sat', 'on'], ['the'], ['mat']], [['The', 'cat', 'sat'], ['on'], ['the'], ['mat']], [['The'], ['cat'], ['sat'], ['on'], ['the', 'mat']], [['The'], ['cat'], ['sat'], ['on', 'the'], ['mat']], [['The'], ['cat'], ['sat', 'on'], ['the'], ['mat']], [['The'], ['cat', 'sat'], ['on'], ['the'], ['mat']], [['The', 'cat'], ['sat'], ['on'], ['the'], ['mat']], [['The'], ['cat'], ['sat'], ['on'], ['the'], ['mat']]]
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.  (I think the argument to partition should be "input_list", not "iterable", though? Or am I missing sometning?)

Comment: It could be changed, yes. I just kept iterable because that function is not my own code.